# What happens if an IV drip with a saline solution slips out of the vein, but keeps dripping into the body?

Tags: hematology, hydration

A patient has a saline solution IV drip into the vein. They have somehow moved around and the needle has fallen out of the vein, but remained in the body. Nobody has noticed and for a few hours water has accumulated like a balloon in the arm.

What happens? Is it dangerous? If untreated, would the body absorb the water, or would it remain as a balloon / pocket? If a pocket of water forms, what is the treatment?

Comment: Is this a question about a real case? Or are you possibly asking about a homework question? (It sounds kind of like that to me)

Comment: Real case. I've been sent home with a puppy and an IV. It is the middle of the night. Closest vet is 6 hours away, and only available in the morning.

Comment: @Bob we need to know where the pocket is exactly.

Comment: @caseyr547 above where the needle was inserted. Between elbow and shoulder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**CALL YOUR VET ASAP.** The following information is ***NOT*** from a medical or veterinary professional. It is based off of human physiology and doesn't necessarily apply to other mammals. I cannot guarantee the accuracy or effectiveness of any information that follows.

> They have somehow moved around and the needle has fallen out of the vein, but remained in the body. Nobody has noticed and for a few hours water has accumulated like a balloon in the arm.

This is called "infiltration":

[image: Diagram of Infiltration and Extravasation] [image]

> Is it dangerous?

It can be, depending on what was in the IV.

> If untreated, would the body absorb the water, or would it remain as a balloon / pocket? If a pocket of water forms, what is the treatment?

Taken from [here](http://w3.rn.com/news/clinical_insights_details.aspx?Id=34318):

"If the infiltration is severe, you may consider the application of a compress in addition to elevating the affected limb. Check your institution’s policy regarding which type of compress (warm or cold) should be applied. Generally speaking, if the infiltration solution was isotonic, a warm compress is used to alleviate discomfort and help absorb the infiltration by increasing circulation to the affected area. However, sloughing can occur from the application of a warm compress to an area infiltrated with certain medications such as potassium chloride. In certain situations, a cold compress is recommended."

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Unfortunately the vet was not available to call, but by morning, the water pocket had been sloughed into the body. I think we dodged a bullet.

Comment: It seems like this was 'infiltration' as you say.

Comment: When we told the vet in the morning, they didn't even seem the slightest concerned this happened. I dont know - but I think that is weird. If we had of been asleep, this would have continued for another 6 hours. I am surprised they sent us home with an IV in the first place without telling us all the possible issues, such as blood clotting in the tubes (which happened earlier) due to poor circulation.

Comment: Well, I simply do not know how dangerous it is. My *intuition* says it's not particularly dangerous since the extra fluid is, eventually, absorbed. However, I'm not a medical professional and don't know the circumstances that dictates when it becomes dangerous. Thus, the big warning at the beginning. Better safe than sorry. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The most common IV drip that would be sent home with a pet owner is Ringer's solution. This fluid is also commonly injected as a subcutaneous (between muscle and skin) bolus into both cats and dogs. Although IV administration is more efficient, this fluid is completely harmless if an IV catheter were dislodged allowing it to accumulate in the surrounding tissue.